# selenium script to check the placeholder value of the Lastname textbox

Tags: java, selenium, getelementbyid

Getting error: Could not find or load main class PageLocator.
Please check if methods are fine and if i am calling the methods correctly in main class

I am in need to test the placeholders of the fields

```
public class PageLocator    //DO NOT Change the class Name
    {
    
     static  WebDriver driver;
     static   WebElement LN ;
    
    public WebDriver createDriver()  //DO NOT change the method signature
    {
            
           
            DriverSetup ds = new DriverSetup();
            driver =  ds.getWebDriver();
            return driver;
    }
    
    public WebElement getPageLocator(WebDriver driver)  //DO NOT change the method signature
    {
       /*Replace this comment by () code statement to get the WebElement of 'Lastname'*/
       /*Find the element by id */
       
       LN = driver.findElement(By.id("lastname"));
       
       return LN;
    
    }
    public String getName(WebElement element)  //DO NOT change the method signature
    {
        //Get the attribute value from the element and return it
       
       getPageLocator pll = new getPageLocator(element);
        String LastN = pll.getAttribute("placeholder");
        return LastN;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        PageLocator pl=new PageLocator();
        WebElement LN = pl.getPageLocator(driver);
        String name=pl.getName(LN);
        System.out.println("The Lastname is "+name);
    }
```

Comment: from where you are using driver variable in this `WebElement LN = pl.getPageLocator(driver);`

Comment: I  just created a variable LN WebEement to store the value

Comment: I am asking about the `driver` variable

Comment: I have created a static webdriver driver variable

Comment: are you sure the name of the class/package is correct on the ***pipeline*** that calls it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `createDriver()` method in the `main` method.

So your `main` method should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    PageLocator pl=new PageLocator();
    WebDriver driver = pl.createDriver();
    WebElement LN = pl.getPageLocator(driver);
    String name=pl.getName(LN);
    System.out.println("The Lastname is "+name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getName method should be

```
public String getName(WebElement element)
{
    String LastN=LN.getAttribute("placeholder");
    return LastN;
}
```